# draw 3D sphere in c++ without OpenGL

Tags: 3d, geometry, raytracing

I need to make a sphere ray-tracer in c/c++ without the use of OpenGL. I'm confused though at how to put a sphere or light in a scene without any gl functions. Can someone please explain how this can be done?

Comment: Does the program need to be real-time? If so, you can use SDL or some other API that gives you access to the framebuffer. If not, you can output an image file.

Comment: Your question is extremely vague, edit your question and ask specific questions and give us the relevant details of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Raytracing has nothing to do with opengl. It can be done with a desktop calculator.

The point is that it's pure geometry done with vectors, that are essentially three floating point variables. (or even integers).

You "put" your camera at origin: ox=0, oy=0, oz=0.

You "put" your sphere at 5 "meters" or units towards z-axis:    sx=0,sy=0,sz=5;

You start to cast rays at 90 degree Field of View towards z-axis:

```
for (i=-1;i<1; i+=0.01) {
   for (j=-1;j<1; j+=0.01) {
       dx=i; dy=j;dz=1;  // perhaps you then need to normalize the "vector" dx,dy,dz
       // check if the ray hits the sphere with radius 2.3 (located at 0,0,5)

       // if it does, calculate the angle of the normal of the hit point and
       // the light source at position lx=1,ly=-0.5;lz=-2.33;

       // if normal dot lightray is positive, calculate angle, apply Phong model

       // add lambertian model, distance attenuation, fog, texturemapping

  }
 }
```

In the end you have calculated pixel intensities or color values for ~200 x 200 image. This example uses 90 degree FoV.

Comment: HTML5, javascript and 2d-canvas can be used to simulate (almost in real time) the math. From c/c++ I suggest simply outputting to some raw format byte per byte. No render buffer needed. PPM can be read by irfanview and many other image viewing applications.

Comment: Sorry if I am totally wrong here but just a few clarifications... In your example, vector dx, dy, dz is the ray coming from the light source, right? And also, to calculate if it hits the sphere I would just use the equation of a circle and compare to see if the ray hit somewhere within that set of points?

Comment: In classical ray tracing the ray (dx,dy,dz) is not cast from light sources, but from the eye. Ray to sphere hit points is calculated by solving directly the equation: |t*D - S|^2 = R^2, where there are 0,1 or 2 solutions as this will be quadratic equation. Get the closest 't'. That's the "entry point", unless one t<0 and the other t>0, in which case the camera was inside the sphere. Also from the discriminator of quadratic equation one immediately sees how many solutions there are.